# What's a good substitute for a pocket knife that can be carried on-board a plane?

Tags: air-travel, gear, airport-security, hand-luggage

I always used to pack a pocket knife in my checked luggage when travelling, but now that I'm travelling with carry-on bags only, security restrictions prevent me from bringing a pocket knife.

Is there a good substitute for a pocket knife that has a good selection of tools (for example, screwdrivers, bottle opener, small scissors), but no knives, so it is legal to carry on board?

Comment: "Tools" may be turned back at the discretion of the inspector, in my experience.

Comment: I agree. I have had experiences where I could bring my personal devices through just fine, but the "Work Equipment" I was carrying was inspected and questioned thoroughly.

Comment: @user58700: What did the work equipment say in response? :-P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is called the [Knifeless Leatherman](http://www.leatherman.com/product/Knifeless_Fuse).

- 8 in | 19 cm Ruler
- Bottle Opener
- Can Opener
- Hard-wire Cutters
- Large Screwdriver
- Needlenose Pliers
- Phillips Screwdriver
- Regular Pliers
- Scissors
- Small Screwdriver
- Wire Cutters
- Wire Stripper

but importantly, NO KNIVES!

Comment: The Knifeless Fuse is listed in the "Retired" section of the Leatherman website, so it may be harder to find.

However, they also have the Style PS which is smaller and lighter, and also knifeless, and is a current model.  This may be perfect for me.

Comment: I doubt that this is allowed in cabin. See [TSA: Prohibited items](http://www.tsa.gov/travelers/airtravel/prohibited/permitted-prohibited-items.shtm)

Comment: This sounds far more dangerous than a water bottle...

Comment: @Mark Mayo: Have you actually got such an item through security anywhere?

Comment: Me, no, but the only thing I take in the cabin is my medication, jacket and netbook.  Everything else is checked.

Comment: I imagine it's just as easy to seriously injure someone with a screwdriver as it is with any bladed cutting implement. Also, I think scissors aren't allowed in carry-on either.

Comment: If it has an 8-inch ruler, then I'm assuming that the tool is larger than 7 inches. [TSA](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items#7) states that tools over 7" are not allowed on board. Incidentally, though, screw drivers under 7" actually are allowed. Hammers, drills, and drill bits aren't allowed, though. It appears that scissors actually are allowed if their blade length is shorter than 4 inches.

Comment: Each side of the handle is 4" long, when you extend the tool horizontally, it becomes an 8" ruler. But folded in half, it's 4" which would fit in the rules.

Comment: Fwiw, I was disallowed a tool that's only a multi-bit screwdriver.  Size doesn't seem to matter: anything tool-like is taken away.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a bicycle Y-wrench, about three inches across, small enough to forget in  my pocket, refused.  They did let me mail it to myself, which was approximately the same cost as replacing it.

Scissors are definitely a no-no.  About a dozen years ago I traveled with my 80-year-old mother.  She had a small scissors caught inside the lining of her purse, about the size of the scissors blade of a Swiss-army knife.  It showed on the X-ray, and the bag made multiple passes through the machine until they managed to find it and confiscate it.

I agree with the observation that ANYTHING tool-like is likely not to make it.

Comment: The question makes sense in an international context, because the ban on knives is very widespread. However, this answer seems to be specific to one country, but doesn't say which. Please be explicit about where this happened, so that people can make their own decisions as to how far to extrapolate your experience.